# Magento 2 - Reload totals cart after ajax change quantity

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, magento2

I want to use ajax to change the quantity of one item on the cart magento 2 cart page.

I have added this javascript:

```
$('.cart.item .qty').on({
    change: function() {
        var post_url = $(this).attr('data-post-url');

        $.post(post_url, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $(".form-cart").replaceWith(data.cart_html);
            $("#cart-totals").replaceWith(data.totals_html);
            $("#cart-totals").trigger('contentUpdated');
        }, "json");
    }
});
```

The value of data.totals_html is

```
<div id="cart-totals" class="cart-totals" data-bind="scope:'block-totals'">
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#cart-totals": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {"components":{"block-totals":....}
</script>
```

When I change the quantity, the total component content is not refresh..

Anyone have an idea for dynamically update the total component after replace the html code?

Answer (score 3):

**Reload totals cart after ajax change quantity**

1. Step

In your custom them create ( Magento_Theme/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml )

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="cart.ajax.qty.update"  template="Magento_Theme::js.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

2.Step

creat js.phtml file ( Magento_Theme/templates/js.phtml )

```
<script>
require ([
        'jquery',
    ],
    function ($) {
       $(window).on("load", function () {
            require([
                'custom'
            ]);
        });
    });
```

3. Step
create custom.js file in theme web folder ( Namespace/Yourtheme/web/js/custom.js )

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
     ], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
        var form = $('form#form-validate');
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            showLoader: true,
            success: function (res) {
                var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                var sections = ['cart'];

                $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

                // The mini cart reloading
                customerData.reload(sections, true);

                // The totals summary block reloading
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                getTotalsAction([], deferred);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.log(err.Message);
            }
        });
       });
      });
    });
```

4.Step  ( map your js file )

Create requirejs-config.js on your theme root ( Namespace/yourtheme/requirejs-config.js)

```
var config = {
   map: {
    '*': {
        custom:'js/custom'
    }
  }
};
```

Now the qty update work using ajax 
If have any issue ask in comment.

Comment: Great and simple answer :). However, for some reason, when reloading the cart totals this way, it will never have an estimated shipping cost. It will always be zero :(

Comment: Where we apply quantity increment and decrements.

Comment: Qty increment decrement not working if i run this code. Do you know how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

You can consult this way to ajax re-load block totals in cart:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
], function($, getPaymentInformationAction, totals) {
    $('.cart.item .qty').on({
        change: function() {
            var post_url = $(this).attr('data-post-url');
            $.post(post_url, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                //custom your update
                $(".form-cart").replaceWith(data.cart_html);
                $("#cart-totals").replaceWith(data.totals_html);
                //reload block total
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                totals.isLoading(true);
                getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
                $.when(deferred).done(function() {
                    totals.isLoading(false);
                });
                //end
            }, "json");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following js code -

```
require(
[
   'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
   'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default'
],
function(
   quote,
   totalsDefaultProvider
) {
     totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
  }
);
```

For more information, please refer to [this article](https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/magento-2-triggering-totals-refresh-in-cart/).

**Disclaimer: I am the CEO of MexBS (The company who published this article)**

Comment: Would this still be true for Magento 2.2.6? I tried this - but unlike Surendra's answer it does not trigger reloading the totals block in the cart.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code in cartQtyUpdate.js to this one

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
        var form = $('form#form-validate');
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            showLoader: true,
            success: function (res) {
                var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                var sections = ['cart'];

                $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

                /* Minicart reloading */
                customerData.reload(sections, true);

                /* Totals summary reloading */
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                getTotalsAction([], deferred);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.log(err.Message);
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.alo_qty', function() {
        var form = $('form#form-validate');
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            showLoader: true,
            success: function (res) {
                var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                var sections = ['cart'];

                $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

                /* Minicart reloading */
                customerData.reload(sections, true);

                /* Totals summary reloading */
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                getTotalsAction([], deferred);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.log(err.Message);
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

now it works well